# Jupyter-like Markdown for Visual Studio

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

When I used Jupyter for Python programming, one of my favorite features was the fact that I could embed Markdown code to add in textual explanations and figures to help navigate and understand the code. Below is a good example of what I'm referring to.

**Is there a way to obtain this feature in Visual Studio when programming in C#?**

[image]